# How to insert data into MySQL through a URL?

Tags: java, mysql, database, url, parameters

So I have a MySQL db called "Example". In the db, I have a table with a row called "Rank" and "Name". I want to be able to input "Rank" and "Name" values into the db through URL.

I have made a Tomcat server through Eclipse, and would like help on the java code in order to use the parameters to send data to the db.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

The question itself shows a 'GET' method. the accepted answer shows a 'POST' method.
All the handling should be done on your server.

This is a code for sending it the right values to the server.

Do you need help with the server itself?
I know how to do that in php, if that helps you

Comment: yes, help with the server inserting values to the DB would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far?
If you're using Tomcat, I can't help you (maybe this like would. http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-mysql) since I have no knowledge in Tomcat.
I can however, help if you want php to connect to a DB, but I dunno if that's an option. don't know how your server is setted up.

Comment: please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893462/how-to-input-data-into-mysql-from-eclipse